# Best way to write a subcomponent of a modified selector in BEM/SCSS

Tags: sass, bem

I want a nice elegant way in SCSS to write BEM subcomponents without being verbose, and modify them using the parent class.

```
.container.container--red .container__title {
}
```

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
.container {
   &.container--red {
      &__title {
      }
   }  
}
```

But this doesn't work because it assumes the selector I need is .container--red__title

Answer (score 1):

scss:

```
.container {
    $root: &;

    &--red {
        #{$root}__title {
            color: red;
        }
    }  
}
```

output:

```
.container--red .container__title {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this what you would want to use?

`.container {
    &--red {}
    &__title {}
}`

Compiling to

`.container {}
.container--red {}
.container__title {}`

Don't forget that hierarchy still counts in sass because you need to think about the compilation output.